# Ember data - How to update record

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I did implement some code with ember-data talking to a sinatra json-app. Method findAll works as expected and load of records. 
Also I did implement the updateRecord-method in the DS.Store.create, but don't really know how to update and commit. Please, see the code here (for sake of brevity, I didn't include the jquery functions): http://pastie.org/3197008

I tried the following:

```
a = Todos.records.objectAt(0).set("text", "should be so")
a.store.commit()
```

But I get the following error: `TypeError: Object (subclass of DS.State) has no method 'enter'`

How should I update records? Or did I forget to implement something for the update?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem.  I think this is a bug in ember-data.  The problem is that the code was not properly initializing certain substates, and those substates were not state instances but rather state classes.

I fixed the problem by defining a function that generates a new state instance (with properly created substates) each time it is called.  You can find my changes [here](https://github.com/kyptin/data/commit/61ec1843826efe4dc6e85151f0384b94193f8d49).

I also requested that the ember-data folks pull my fix, so hopefully this issue will disappear soon.  You can view the [pull request](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/48) for discussion.

Comment: Thanks! This bug is getting me crazy :-)

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem this morning. Use the emberjs git version

Comment: yes, you have to pull and build ember-data if you want the latest... they haven't posted a full download/build in a while